# How to switch from int to string in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So basically I want to slip in two numbers say 1 and 10 and I want the console to print a string that says this "12345678910". I am thinking a for loop with an int to string conversion method but what I can't figure out is the printing. Any hints?

```
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 10;
for (int number1; number1 <= number2; number1++){
    NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", firstNumber];
    NSLog(@"%@", myNewString); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to append each number to the string? Simply use a mutable string:

```
NSMutableString* mutableString = [NSMutableString string];
for (int number = number1; number <= number2; number++) {
    [mutableString appendFormat:@"%d", number];
}
NSLog(@"%@", mutableString);
```

Comment: xcode says "there is no know class method for selector "appendFormat"

Comment: It's because 'mutableString' needs to be declared as a NSMutableString rather than NSString.

Comment: Yes, @Orkster is right. I accidentally wrote `NSString` instead of `NSMutableString`. He suggested the correct edit but 3 out of 5 reviewers thought the edit was wrong when it was clearly correct… have fixed it.